java.util.EnumSet.forEach claiming unreported exception
Compiling this Java code:
package com.acme.javasdk;

public class Enum_Test
{
    public enum MyEnum
    {
        NoOption (0x00),
        Option1  (0x01),
        Option2  (0x02),
        Option3  (0x04),
        Option4  (0x08),
        ;

        long value;

        MyEnum(long value)
        {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public long getValue()
        {
            return(value);
        }
    }

    MyEnum option;

    public void setOption(
        java.util.EnumSet<MyEnum> options
    ) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        this.option = MyEnum.NoOption;

        options.forEach(
            option ->
            addOption(option)
        );
    }

    public void addOption(
        MyEnum option
    ) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        long lNewValue = this.option.value |= option.value;

        if(lNewValue == MyEnum.NoOption.value)
        {
            throw new java.lang.Exception(
                "Invalid option."
            );
        }

        this.option.value = lNewValue;
    }

}

yields the following error, even though the method declares that java.lang.Exception may be thrown:
Enum_Test.java:37: error: unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    [javac]             addOption(option)
    [javac]                      ^
    [javac] 1 error

Even if I handle the exception in the method:
    public void setOption(
        java.util.EnumSet<MyEnum> options
    ) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        this.option = MyEnum.NoOption;
        try
        {
            options.forEach(
                option ->
                addOption(option)
            );
        }
        catch(java.lang.Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }

it still generates an error that calling addOption(option) may throw an unhandled exception:
Enum_Test.java:38: error: unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    [javac]                 addOption(option)
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] 1 error


The forEach method takes a Consumer. The lambda is implementing that interface's accept method. That method is not declared to throw any checked exceptions. You are calling addOption in the lambda, and that method is declared to throw a checked exception. Since accept cannot throw a checked exception, you would have to handle the exception in the lambda. That means moving your try-catch into the lambda around the addOption call. Or remove the throws Exception from addOption if that method shouldn't be able to throw a checked exception. See duplicates for more information.

One solution you might consider is having addOption throw an unchecked exception, like IllegalArgumentException, instead of a checked exception. The second duplicate goes into the differences between checked and unchecked exceptions.

Thanks @Slaw , very helpful.  I started down the path of using an unchecked exception but it started getting messy.  I simply changed the code to use an iterator.  2 lines of code more than the lambda, but cleaner than the other approaches AFAICT.

Skipping the exception issues, the code makes no sense as it is updating the field value of MyEnum.NoOptions, so for second use NoOptions is better named SomeOptions as it has state of previous use.

@DuncG it seems, the author did not understand that enum types in Java are objects and Java objects are always handled by reference. It looks like someone would try to implement an enum set in C, which makes even less sense here, as the input is already an EnumSet…

Adding fuel to the flames, long lNewValue = this.option.value |= option.value; does already modify this.option.value, making the this.option.value = lNewValue; at the end obsolete but further, the subsequent condition lNewValue == MyEnum.NoOption.value will always be true , as this.option points to the same object as MyEnum.NoOption. So it will always throw an exception. The use of |= instead of | can’t even be explained with “applying C logic”, as it would be wrong in that language too, to modify the variable before applying the validity check.

@DuncG , @Holger Thanks for reviewing and commenting.  You're right, but the code here is a bastardized version of the original.  It was stripped down (and some portions changed) in haste just to get a small repro of the compiler error.  Incidentally the production code is used along with JNI, and the actual member this.option is a long, not MyEnum.
